# how much storage space is required for hyperledger peer distributed ledger?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I was reading about the Hyperledger v1.0 and was thinking about this scenario:
In a busy Hyperledger network of 1000++ peers actively submitting transactions. There are sure to have some peers that contribute few transactions/month as compared to other more active peers that have 10,000 transactions/month.

It does not seem fair for the smaller-sized peer to store the huge distributed ledger that contains all ledger transactions made by all peers. How is this handled in Hyperledger? How much is actual storage used by the distributed ledger? Is there a upper limit on how much transactions can be in the ledger?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The Hyperledger Fabric does not store every transaction from every peer. The channel architecture provides that a peer only sees (and stores) the transactions that pertain to that channel.

As to what are the storage requirements, the ledger grows forever. Capability to checkpoint and archive the ledger will be added in the future but for now you need to plan accordingly.

Comment: I understand that from Hyperledger v1.0 onwards, transactions can be across channels, thus providing a way for ensuring data privacy for all peers, while maintaining a shared ledger for all transactions.

Comment: Each Peer only stores the transactions that are executed in this Peers channel. A Peer can take part in more than a channel, so it will store the transactions from those different channels. In Hyperledger Fabric, the Ordering Serice creates the blocks. Each block stores transactions from the same channel, i.e. in a block there woulnd't be transactions from different channels.

Comment: What if each peer is a competitor company and they require privacy so that competitors cannot see each other's transaction data. In this case, should each peer reside in a separate channel for total isolation? or in the same channel and use some visibility features to enforce privacy?

Comment: peers don't reside in a channel, they participate in one or more channels. Transaction data is only shared in the context of the channel, so only the peers and orderer that participate in the channel.